# How to enabled and disabled modules in Yii2?

Tags: module, yii2, yii-modules

In google no more information about modules enabled and disabled so I am troubling here.

I have build some modules in yii2 like `users`, `payments`, `subscriptions`, `news` etc. I want to disabled `subscriptions` modules. Is it possible?

**Edit:** Enable and Disable function should allow for end user.

Comment: Just remove it from the config..?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @jagsler I want to disabled and enabled from user end. Not removing manually from coding

Answer (score 2):

I would place the following code in the module class(es) that support being disabled/enabled.

So for every module (`users`, `subscriptions`, `news`, etc) you have module class somewhere that extends `\yii\base\Module`. Place code like this in every module class and check the appropriate setting.

```
public function init() {
    if (!$this->_isModuleEnabled()) {
        // This can also be another exception of course.
        throw new \Exception("This module isn't enabled.");
    }
    parent::init();
}

private function _isModuleEnabled() {
    /**
     * Probably check some setting in the database or someting. Then
     * return true or false depending on that setting.
     */
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think this solution is good enough. @jagsler, can we access DB from init(), so that we can disable the module using UI/DB without changing the source code.